# Recorrer un listview con un ciclo en vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview, bucles, foreach

Tengo dos listview que uso para asignar o rebocar permisos de usuario, funciona perfectamente, pero actualmente paso los permisos de uno a uno, quisiera marcar varios y pasarlos todos a la vez.

```
Private Sub revocarPermiso(ByVal usuario As Integer, ByVal permiso As Integer)
    Try
        Dim param(2) As OleDbParameter
        Dim parametroOut(0) As OleDb.OleDbParameter
        Dim bool As Integer = 1
        param(0) = New OleDbParameter("@PBOOL", bool)
        param(1) = New OleDbParameter("@PID_USUARIO", usuario)
        param(2) = New OleDbParameter("@ID_PERMISO_USER", permiso)
        parametroOut(0) = New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@PSALIDA", OleDb.OleDbType.Numeric)
        parametroOut(0).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

        If (ad.ejecutaSP("RRHH.SP_ASIGNARPERMISO", param)) Then
            MsgBox("Se revoco el permiso", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Guardado")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error al asignar el permsiso " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Este es el codigo que estoy usando
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No estaria entendiendo tu problema. No sabes recorrer un listview?

Comment: digamos que si, estoy usando un ciclo for each pero tengo un error        For Each item As ListViewItem In lv_permiso.SelectedItems.Items pero no se la sintaxis para pasar los parametros

Comment: param(0) = New OleDbParameter("@PID_USUARIO", (item.Tag(0).Value.ToString())) tengo esto pero el ciclo for For Each item As ListViewItem In lv_permiso.SelectedItems.Items  me dice que items no es un mienbro de listview

Comment: No deberia ser For Each item As ListViewItem In lv_permiso.SelectedItems???

Comment: Mmmmm estoy abarcando el problema de manera incorrecta,                       Private Sub btn_asignar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_asignar.Click
        If lv_usuario.SelectedItems.Count > 0 And lv_permiso.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            asignarPermiso(CInt(lv_usuario.SelectedItems(0).Tag), CInt(lv_permiso.SelectedItems(0).Tag))
            carga_permisos(CInt(lv_usuario.SelectedItems(0).Tag))
            carga_permisosasignados(CInt(lv_usuario.SelectedItems(0).Tag))
            TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0
            'End If
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: en el evento click de mi boton asignar tomo como parametro la posicion 1 de dos listview para crear las condiciones para mi consulta, como deberia estructurar el ciclo, ahora lo tengo a si

Comment: For Each item As ListViewItem In lv_permiso.Items
                For columna As Integer = 0 To item.SubItems.Count - 1

Comment: usa el boton [edit]. en comentarios no se entiende nada

Comment: puse mi formulario para agregar contexto a lo que necesito hacer, para agreagar un permiso, selecciono un usuario del listview de la izquirda luego el permiso en el listview de permisos y pues luego al boton

Comment: El codigo es lo que tenemos que ver

Comment: pondre una captura para que sea mas claro

Comment: No. Una captura del codigo no. El codigo tiene que ir como texto

Comment: como lo hago, si lo pongo por aca me dice que me excedí de caracteres

Comment: 'Private Sub btn_asignar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_asignar.Click
        If lv_usuario.SelectedItems.Count > 0 And lv_permiso.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            asignarPermiso(CInt(lv_usuario.SelectedItems(0).Tag), CInt(lv_permiso.SelectedItems(0).Tag))
            carga_permisos(CInt(lv_usuario.SelectedItems(0).Tag))
            carga_permisosasignados(CInt(lv_usuario.SelectedItems(0).Tag))
            TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0
            'End If
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: este seria mi evento click